# IE onclick doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery

I make a button dynamically with jquery after an event

```
var $btnRow = $('<input />')
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .attr('id', 'myID')
    .attr('onclick', 'AddChildRow(this);')
    .val('Row');
$btnRow.css({ 'width': '38px', 'padding': '0' });
```

the html generated is like :

```
<input type="button" id="myID" onclick="AddChildRow(this);" value="Row" style="width: 38px; padding: 0pt;">
```

I have a AddChildRow function in my js file. It's working perfectly in FF, but not in IE (it does not call the AddChildRow ). Has someone had the same problem before? This button is part of dynamic DIV -> Table -> TR -> TD schema. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: jQuery makes it easy to bind event handlers; don't use `attr()` to set `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding the button click event differently and use the jQuery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event

```
var $btnRow = $('<input />')
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .attr('id', 'myID')
    .val('Row')
    .click(AddChildRow)
    .css({ 'width': '38px', 'padding': '0' });

$("div").append($btnRow);

function AddChildRow()
{
    alert(this.id);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/nSCHn/

**Tested and working in IE 6/7/8/9**

Comment: thanks that was the solution. Actually I just kind of translate js file to Jquery by copying and pasting the old file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery's live() method.
For example:

$("#myId").live('click', AddChildRow);

And insert the myId button on the page anytime you want since the live() method will "discover" it and bind the AddChildRow function to it.